# Управление образования администрации: строчная или заглавная

Tags: орфография

> У(у)правление образования, спорта и молодежной политики администрации Н-ского района.

Вообще слово "управление" часто пишут со строчной буквы, но здесь, похоже, официальное название, вот я и задумалась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как часть официального названия "Управление" и может писаться со прописной, если это превое слово в таком наименовании и это наименование приводится точно и порлностью. Хотя и тут, конечно, можно долго спорить.
Есть ещё иногда манера писать "Управление" со строчной в качестве условного наименования конретного управления (по типу "ниже именуемый Заказчик"), но пока такой подход, насколько мне известно, не нормирован.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду "с прописной"? У Вас поставлена именно такая.

Comment: Спасибо, с прописной конечно. Так долго формулировал, что начал за здравие...